# Loading an image from disk in ViewPager effeciently

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager that displays big full screen images from disk, and I'm using Universal Image Loader to load the bitmaps:

```
public class QuranImagePagerAdapter extends AbstractPagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        .....
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.displayImage("file:///" + path, imageView);
        .....
    }
}
```

I'm noticing that the app is not 100% smooth when scrolling. I'm thinking its because of loading from disk in the UI thread.
Do I have to put this loading inside a background thread/AsyncTask?

Comment: Try using libraries like Glide or Picasso, they both load images asynchronously..

Comment: I would expect Universal Image Loader has the same functionality no?